# What is the idMso for the spelling/grammar context menu?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-addins, word-2010

I'm looking for an *idMso* id for a contextmenu in microsoft word 2010.
The contextmenu id I'm looking for contains a few of the following items:
-"Ignore All"
-"Add To Dictionary"
-"Edit Hyperlink"
-"Remove Hyperlink"

I've searched through the documentation of MS-office and all of their idMso's and tried a fair bit of them. Dispite this I can not seem to find the corrent idMso for this contextmenu. My best description for this contextmenu would be:
-"A contextmenu shown when a user clicks on a wrongly spelled hyperlink"

*idMso's I've already tried:*
-ContextMenuText
-ContextMenuTextEdit
-ContextMenuTextEffect
-ContextMenuTextLinked
-ContextMenuTextTable
-Spelling
-SpellingAndGrammar
-SpellingHideErrors
-SpellingMenu
-SpellingRecheckDocument
-ContextMenuGrammar
-ContextMenuGrammarReading
-ContextMenuHyperlink

*A screenshot of the contextmenu (it's in Dutch, ms-word does not let me change the language)*
[image: ContexteMenu with unknown idMso]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idMso should be `ContextMenuSpell`. I would also do it for `ContextMenuGrammar`

All control identifiers are here

[Office 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=6627)

[Office 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=36798)

[Office 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745)

Comment: I did not have the change to implemnt this untill today. But it seems to work fine. The code that was implemented was:

`<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuSpell">
      <button idMso="HyperlinkEdit" getVisible="HideNormalLink" />
      <button id="ButtonAlterLink_02" label="Bewerk link" insertBeforeMso="HyperlinkOpen" imageMso="HyperlinkOpenExcel" onAction="AlterLink" getVisible="VisibleContextAlter"/>
    </contextMenu>`